# Simulate keyboard input linux

Tags: python, c++, linux, input, keyboard

I work on a project to control my PC with a remote, and a infrared receptor on an Arduino.
I need to simulate keyboard input with a process on linux who will listen arduino output and simulate keyboard input. I can dev it with Python or C++, but i think python is more easy.

After many search, i found many result for... windows u_u
Anyone have a library for this ?
thanks

EDIT: I found that /dev/input/event3 is my keyboard. I think write in to simulate keyboard, i'm searching how do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert input events into the Linux input subsystem, use the user-mode input device driver, uinput. This might help: http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput (Note that while the tutorial references `/dev/input/uinput`, the correct file on my Ubuntu 12.04 PC is `/dev/uinput`.

Comment: oh waw ! Thanks you ! It's just that i needed
I'll try it !!

Comment: The link no longer works

Answer (score 1):

The most generic solution is to use pseudo-terminals: you connect `tttyn` to the standard in and standard out of the program you want to monitor, and use `pttyn` to read and write to it.

Alternatively, you can create two pipes, which you connect to the standard in and standard out of the program to be monitored before doing the `exec`.  This is much simpler, but the pipes look more like a file than a terminal to the program being monitored.

Comment: No, i don't want to focus a window or a process. I want to use my remote like a keyboard.
I found that /dev/input/event3 is my keyboard, now i search to write in...

Comment: Have you tried telnet?  (It uses pseudo-terminals under the hood, in the telnet server, but at least you don't have to worry about it.)